# compile QT and OpenCV together in Ubuntu using qmake

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu

Im writing a OpenCV application and a QT GUI together and im having some issues compiling.
Some background information that might be useful; the OS is Ubuntu 13.10, the output of " qmake --version" is :QMake version 3.0 Using Qt version 5.0.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

The issues starts upon the appearance of one line of code, that being "Mat cvImage" where I declare a Mat object. The way im compiling is first "qmake -project" then "qmake" then i go into my .pro file and add "QT += widgets" and then I type "make", when i do this, i get the error

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile gui2.pro
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB    -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -    I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o main.o     main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:55:2: error: ‘Mat’ was not declared in this scope
  Mat cvImage;
  ^
main.cpp:55:2: note: suggested alternative:   
In file included from main.cpp:20:0:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1683:18: note:   ‘cv::Mat’
 class CV_EXPORTS Mat
                  ^
main.cpp:55:6: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cvImage’
  Mat cvImage;
  ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

To be honest, i have no idea what "In file included from main.cpp:20:0:  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1683:10 note: 'cv :: Mat' " means. I included all the appropriate OpenCV libraries and I dont know how to interpret that line of error output. Below is my code

```
/*****************C++ Libraries******************/
#include <iostream>

/****************User Defined*******************/
#include "function.h"
#include "function.cpp"

/****************Libraries Needed for QT********/
#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include<QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

/************Libraries Needed For OpenCV*******/
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
/** some code that runs a gui ***/


    Mat cvImage; // This is where the problem starts
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I also looked into my Makefile and i dont see any paths or anything to OpenCV libraries so I tried adding them, it caused more problems.

This is the auto-generated Makefile(via the qmake command)

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: gui2
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.0.2) on: Mon Jan 27 12:24:52 2014
# Project:  gui2.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile gui2.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I.
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -m64 -Wl,-O1
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
STRIP         = strip
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = ./

####### Files

SOURCES       = main.cpp moc_function.cpp
OBJECTS       = main.o \
        moc_function.o
DIST          = /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3d.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dquick.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_v8.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/wayland-scanner.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        gui2.pro \
        gui2.pro
QMAKE_TARGET  = gui2
DESTDIR       = 
TARGET        = gui2


first: all
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.cxx.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.C.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

####### Build rules

all: Makefile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)  
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)

Makefile: gui2.pro /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3d.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dquick.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_v8.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/wayland-scanner.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        gui2.pro \
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.prl \
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.prl \
        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.prl
    $(QMAKE) -o Makefile gui2.pro
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/linux.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3d.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_3dquick.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_location.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_v8.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/default_pre.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/uic.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/wayland-scanner.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
gui2.pro:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.prl:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.prl:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.prl:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -o Makefile gui2.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

dist: 
    @test -d .tmp/gui21.0.0 || mkdir -p .tmp/gui21.0.0
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(SOURCES) $(DIST) .tmp/gui21.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents function.h hide/convertImage.h function.cpp .tmp/gui21.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents main.cpp .tmp/gui21.0.0/ && (cd `dirname .tmp/gui21.0.0` && $(TAR) gui21.0.0.tar gui21.0.0 && $(COMPRESS) gui21.0.0.tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname .tmp/gui21.0.0`/gui21.0.0.tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r .tmp/gui21.0.0


clean:compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


####### Sub-libraries

distclean: clean
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(TARGET) 
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

check: first

compiler_rcc_make_all:
compiler_rcc_clean:
compiler_wayland-server-header_make_all:
compiler_wayland-server-header_clean:
compiler_wayland-client-header_make_all:
compiler_wayland-client-header_clean:
compiler_moc_header_make_all: moc_function.cpp
compiler_moc_header_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) moc_function.cpp
moc_function.cpp: /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QObject \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qnamespace.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qconfig.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qfeatures.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsystemdetection.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qprocessordetection.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qlogging.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qflags.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qtypetraits.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsysinfo.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qbytearray.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qrefcount.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_bootstrap.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qgenericatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_msvc.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_integrity.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qoldbasicatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_vxworks.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_power.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_aarch64.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_alpha.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_armv7.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_armv6.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_armv5.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_bfin.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_ia64.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_mips.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_s390.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_sh4a.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_sparc.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_x86.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_gcc.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_unix.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qarraydata.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstringbuilder.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qalgorithms.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qiterator.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcoreevent.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qscopedpointer.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qmetatype.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qvarlengtharray.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcontainerfwd.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qisenum.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject_impl.h \
        function.h
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/moc $(DEFINES) $(INCPATH) function.h -o moc_function.cpp

compiler_wayland-code_make_all:
compiler_wayland-code_clean:
compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_uic_make_all:
compiler_uic_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: compiler_moc_header_clean 

####### Compile

main.o: main.cpp function.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QObject \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qnamespace.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qconfig.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qfeatures.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsystemdetection.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qprocessordetection.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qlogging.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qflags.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qtypeinfo.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qtypetraits.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsysinfo.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs_impl.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstring.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qchar.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qbytearray.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qrefcount.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qbasicatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_bootstrap.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qgenericatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_msvc.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_integrity.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qoldbasicatomic.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_vxworks.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_power.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_aarch64.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_alpha.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_armv7.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_armv6.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_armv5.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_bfin.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_ia64.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_mips.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_s390.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_sh4a.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_sparc.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_x86.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_cxx11.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_gcc.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qatomic_unix.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qarraydata.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstringbuilder.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qalgorithms.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qiterator.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcoreevent.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qscopedpointer.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qmetatype.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qvarlengtharray.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcontainerfwd.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qisenum.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject_impl.h \
        function.cpp \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QApplication \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qapplication.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qeventloop.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qwindowdefs_win.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qpoint.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsize.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qcursor.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qdesktopwidget.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qmargins.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpaintdevice.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qrect.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpalette.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qcolor.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qrgb.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstringlist.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qdatastream.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qiodevice.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qpair.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qregexp.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qstringmatcher.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qbrush.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qvector.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qmatrix.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpolygon.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qregion.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qline.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qtransform.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpainterpath.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qimage.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpixmap.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qshareddata.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qfont.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qfontmetrics.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qfontinfo.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qsizepolicy.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qkeysequence.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qevent.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qvariant.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qmap.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qdebug.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qtextstream.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qlocale.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qset.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcontiguouscache.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qurl.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qurlquery.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qfile.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qfiledevice.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qvector2d.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qtouchdevice.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qguiapplication.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qinputmethod.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QWidget \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QGridLayout \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qgridlayout.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qlayout.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qlayoutitem.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qboxlayout.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QSpinBox \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qspinbox.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractspinbox.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qvalidator.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QLabel \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qlabel.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qframe.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QGraphicsScene \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qgraphicsscene.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpen.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QGraphicsView \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qgraphicsview.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qpainter.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qtextoption.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qscrollarea.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qabstractscrollarea.h \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QGraphicsPixmapItem \
        /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qgraphicsitem.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o main.cpp

moc_function.o: moc_function.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o moc_function.o moc_function.cpp

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

Comment: what's about opencv namespace? `cv::Mat` or using `namespace cv`;

Comment: @itwasntpete , thats a good point, but when I do that, i get the following error ... main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x69): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x54): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gui2] Error 1

Comment: that is a linker error. you have to link your compilation against the lib. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904117/compiling-and-linking-opencv-in-ubuntu-12-04) or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) post.

Comment: i think my issue is linking...but see, im using QT so qmake is the one generating the Makefile. I know how to make OpenCV files compile and link with no issues, the problem is that im using both QT and OpenCV and QT auto-generates the Makefile and I dont know what im supposed to do about it. I tried including "LDFLAGS+=`pkg-config --libs opencv` " in CFLAGS and i tried including this line " LDFLAGS      += `pkg-config --libs opencv`", no success

Comment: @itwasntpete , ive included my Makefile in the original post

Comment: in your project file from qt you can insert flags which will take place in the generated makefile. [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html) is a list of options. you have to insert something like `LIBS += -L/path/to/lib -lname_of_lib` as you would do it in the makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that all I had to do was include the libraries that i needed into "LIBS" in the Makefile. So this is the solution,at the end of LIBS in the Makefile or at the bottom add the line

```
`LIBS += pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

this line can actually be added anywhere in the "Compiler, tools and options" section of the Makefile(refer to the Makefile code posted in the original question).

Additionally, my lack of "namespace" was also an issue!

Answer (score 2):

As clang is trying to tell you, you forgot the openCV namespace.

use either:

```
cv::Mat cvImage;
```

or

```
using namespace cv;
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#cv-namespace).